# How to get @PathVariable value for custom annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-annotations

**I have a controller:**

```
@Authorised(id = "{personId}")
@RequestMapping(value = {"{personId}"}, method = GET)
public void test(@PathVariable PersonId personId) {
    System.out.println(personId); //gets personId
}
```

**Annotation:**

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Authorised {
    String id() default "";
}
```

**Pointcut:**

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(Authorised)")
private void AuthorisedMethod() {}
```

**And the method that has to get {personId} value not string "{personId}":**

```
@Before("AuthorisedMethod()")
public void checkIfIsCurrentlyAuthenticated(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    String methodName = signature.getMethod().getName();
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = signature.getMethod().getParameterTypes();
    Parameter[] parameters = signature.getMethod().getParameters();
    Authorised annotations = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).getAnnotation(Authorised.class);
    String id = annotations.id();
    System.out.println(id); // prints: "{personId}"
    // do the chekcing
    throw new UnauthenticatedUserException();
}
```

**Can it be achieved and how?**

**UPDATE: But what if method argument parameter number don't match with the pointcut args()? I mean that what if specific method has parameter @PathVariable PersonId personId and few more, but poincut needs to know only PersonId personId?**

Like @statut said you have to write args() like that: args(personId,..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `@Before()` annotation to have `PersonId` value and pass this value to aspect, for example

```
@Before("AuthorisedMethod() && args(personId)")
public void checkIfIsCurrentlyAuthenticated(JoinPoint joinPoint, PersonId personId) throws NoSuchMethodException {}
```

To test it I had the following Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(Authorised)")
    private void AuthorisedMethod() {
    }

    @Before("AuthorisedMethod() && args(personId)")
    public void checkIfIsCurrentlyAuthenticated(JoinPoint joinPoint, PersonId personId) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        System.out.println("aspect " + personId.getId());
    }

}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"test"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class Config {
}
```

Test component:

```
@Component
public class Test {

    @Authorised(id = "{personId}")
    public void test(PersonId personId) {
        System.out.println("component " + personId.getId()); //gets personId
    }
}
```

And testNG's runner:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    test.Test test;

    @Test
    public void testName() {
        test.test(new PersonId("id"));
    }

}
```

When I run it, I get printed `"aspect id"` from aspect and `"component id"` from invoked method.

Comment: If I change the annotation and the method signature the way you proposed then checkIfIsCurrentlyAuthenticated method dont't get called at all. Do u know why? @statut

Comment: Could you share your code? I've tried myself and it works.

Comment: Sorry, I can't because it is implemented in a bigger project. So here is only simplified version of it. But still, the problem stays the same :) @statut

Comment: @BrainDead I added some my test code to the answer, please see

Comment: Only thing i didn't have was @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true). After i added it nothing changed.

Comment: If I remove "&& args(personId)" and "PersonId personId" from checkIfIsCurrentlyAuthenticated then the method get's called again.

Comment: @BrainDead Please share your spring, aspectj versions.

Comment: compile "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4"
compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.4"

Comment: I changed the versions to latest 1.8.13 but still the method don't get called.

Comment: If it works when removing the `args()` stuff, it means that your method arguments do not match the pointcut. Does your target method really just have exactly one parameter of type `PersonId`? BTW, I think it is not very helpful to keep people here spending time on guesses instead of sharing your actual code, distilled into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem.

Comment: "it means that your method arguments do not match the pointcut" That was the reason the method didn't get called. I'am sorry about the guessing part! I try to avoid this kind of questions in the future. Thank you @kriegaex

Comment: But what if method argument parameter number don't match with the pointcut args()? I mean that what if specific method has parameter PathVariable PersonId personId and few more, but poincut needs to know only PersonId personId?  @statut

Comment: @BrainDead please try the following: args(personId,..)

Comment: Correct! Ty @statut

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the value of the PathVariable in RequestMapping URL using HandlerInterceptor if that is possible for you.

Write a Handler class that intercepts this Request.

```
public class AuthorisedHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    if (!isResourceHandler(handler) && (handler instanceof HandlerMethod)) {

        HandlerMethod hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        Method method = hm.getMethod();

        Authorised authAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Authorised.class);
        if (authAnnotation != null) {
            String personId = getPersonId(request);
            //Do all your validations Here
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private String getPersonId(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String personId = request.getParameter("personId");
    if(personId == null || personId.equals("")){
        Map pathVariables = (Map) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
        personId = (String) pathVariables.get("personId");
    }
    return personId;
}


private boolean isResourceHandler(Object handler) {
    return handler instanceof ResourceHttpRequestHandler;
}

}
```

And you must configure this Handler bean in spring config xml or Spring Java Config.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.**.AuthorisedHandler" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Now, all the requests will go through this Interceptor. Only which are annotated with @Authorised  will go through.

Comment: Yea, this might be one way how to solve this problem, but this is not the answer for my question :)